# Regular expression in R to capture information inside subsequent quotation marks

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a data file in R which has as an example the following configuration:

```
 [53] "Name:"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [54] "John Brown"
```

For every occurence of "Name" in the file, I just need to extract the "John Brown" part. The file is very messy. I need a regular expression that will extract all the names, ie after "Name:" give me everything in between, but not including the subsequent quotation marks. I am afraid, despite looking through examples of regex, I can't find one that matches my question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It could be as simple as `x[1 + grep("Name:", x)]`, but your sample data is a bit small. If that doesn't work, please provide a more representative dataset, to include (if appropriate) values you do *not* want as well as a few that you do.

Comment: that works fine thx vm pls post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample data:

```
txt <- c("ignore this", "Name:", "James Brown", "American singer", "songwriter", "record producer",
         "Name:", "Bessie Smith", "American blues singer")
```

"We want this":

```
txt[1 + grep("Name:", txt)]
# [1] "James Brown"  "Bessie Smith"
```

What if there is nothing found?

```
txt[1 + grep("name:", txt)]
# character(0)
```

The unit-tester in me suggests you may want to think about some corner-cases:

- `c("Name:", "Name:")`
- `c("Name:", "")` (easily handled with `Filter(nzchar, ...)`, depending on several things)
- `c(..., "Name:")` (nothing after, will currently return `NA`)

(More tests could be useful, perhaps to catch `c("Name:","Name:")`, but that's just the unit-tester in me thinking.

Comment: Thanks! appreciated